# Found incorrect version of Java while installing Jenkins via Ansible

Tags: java, ansible, provisioning

need your assistance, when I'm trying to install Jenkins via Ansible playbook it returns the following issue

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Found an incorrect Java version
Java version found:
java version "1.7.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.9) (7u131-2.6.9-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.131-b00, mixed mode)

Aborting
invoke-rc.d: initscript jenkins, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package jenkins (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jenkins
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I really don't know where to start.  Thanks

Comment: Java 7 is history now, try to use java 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins needs Java 8 these days, you would need to add a task to your Ansible Playbook before that to make sure you get Java 8 in place.

```
- name: Install jdk version 8
  package:
    name: openjdk-8-jdk
    state: present
```

You might also want to set the correct Java link as OS default, in case you end up with several installations in place, with the below code.

```
- name: Select openjdk 8 as system default java
    alternatives:
    name: java
    path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

If you are running this from a role, then insert it under a `pre-tasks:` section before the role definition itself.

Comment: Is openjdk available for Ubuntu 14.04 Like this?

Comment: Openjdk 8 is not available for trusty, but there are ppas available I'm sure

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for installing java8:

```
- name: Ensure the webupd8 launchpad apt repository key is present
  apt_key:
    id: 0xC2518248EEA14886
    keyserver: keyserver.ubuntu.com
    state: present

- name: Add Oracle Java Repository
  apt_repository:
    repo: 'ppa:webupd8team/java'

- name: Accept Java 8 License
  debconf:
    name: 'oracle-java8-installer'
    question: 'shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1'
    value: 'true'
    vtype: 'select'

- name: Install Oracle Java 8
  apt:
    name: {{item}}
    state: latest
  with_items:
    - oracle-java8-installer
    - ca-certificates
    - oracle-java8-set-default
```